# Marionette View and Region

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to show a view for an application region. from documentation i can see every region having element defined and also the backbone view has the el DOM element representation.

honestly, I'm consfused as i'm fairly new to backbone. I'm getting my views from server in the form of html and I don't to define any el for my view all I want is to display whatever html/view I'm receiving in the response to my desired region (that already has an element defined for handling views.)

a simple code sinpet would be highly appreciated also can somebody tell me pros and cons of this along with the one that involves view el.

Answer (score 0):

In backbone, you typically render your views to display information and react to the environment.

What you're looking to do seems like progressive enhancement: reuse the HTML rendered by the server, and attach Backbone event handlers, etc. to the exisiting DOM.

Take a look at this blog post series covering this topic: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/

Part 2 contains the code snippets you're looking for: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/

Comment: I've gone through these blog although he did mention about Marionette but there is not such reference implementation for that matter. I did get the insight about progressive enhancement. But I'm more interesting to find out about Marionette. Need a walkthrough or any other such refernces